# bash, md5sum behaves strange

Tags: bash, md5, md5sum

Why is this different?

```
text="tralala"
echo -n $text | md5sum -
```

result: def7d827536761c20f449f69262ff20f

```
echo -n "tralala" | md5sum -
```

result : 7e4ef92d1472fa1a2d41b2d3c1d2b77a

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you mistakenly did not provide the `-n` (output no newline) flag to echo. See sample from my machine below:

```
$ echo tralala | md5sum
def7d827536761c20f449f69262ff20f  -

$ echo -n tralala | md5sum 
7e4ef92d1472fa1a2d41b2d3c1d2b77a  -

$ text="tralala"
$ echo  $text | md5sum 
def7d827536761c20f449f69262ff20f  -

$ echo -n $text | md5sum 
7e4ef92d1472fa1a2d41b2d3c1d2b77a  -
```

Comment: how can I get rid of the trailing - ?

Comment: to remove the trailing `-`, `echo -n tralala | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'` should do the trick

Comment: @eichertc You could use `sed`, `cut` or `awk` as @BorrajaX suggested.