# Difference between md5sum created by c# and bash

Tags: c#, bash, md5sum

I'm trying understand why when i use a linux md5sum function, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
p="4c4712a4141d261ec0ca8f90379"
Etime="123456"
TOTP=$(echo $Etime$p|md5sum|cut -f1 -d' ')
echo $TOTP
```

I've got: ce007ddfb5eb0ccda6d4a6ddd631c563

But when i trying generate md5sum in c# using this code:

```
        public static string Hash()
        {
            string p = "4c4712a4141d261ec0ca8f90379";
            string Etime = "123456";
            string h = Etime + p ;
            string r = md5test(h);
            return r;
        }

        public static string md5test(string testString)
        {
            byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testString);
            byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
            string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            return hashedString;
        }
```

I've got different value: acb6242ab9ad7a969fb27f10644a0283

I think the problem is in conversion bytes to string, but i'm not sure.
Does anyone could  explain where i make mistake or how to do to have expected value:ce007ddfb5eb0ccda6d4a6ddd631c563

Thanks
Wojtek

Comment: Possible duplicate, at least the same cause: [bash, md5sum behaves strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886492/bash-md5sum-behaves-strange)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the newline at the end of the output of `echo`. Use `echo -n` or `printf` instead:

```
TOTP=$(printf %s "$Etime$p" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewritten the bash part of you test:

```
printf '1234564c4712a4141d261ec0ca8f90379' | md5sum
# prints: acb6242ab9ad7a969fb27f10644a0283  -

printf '1234564c4712a4141d261ec0ca8f90379\n' | md5sum
# prints: ce007ddfb5eb0ccda6d4a6ddd631c563  -
```

The difference is, that echo append a new line character. A solution is to use echo with option -n: `echo  -n ...`. A better solution is, to use printf instead of echo: `printf %s%s' "$Etime" "$p"`